# Umdf2 Hello World Driver, Where to see output?

Tags: windows, windbg, visual-studio-debugging, umdf, outputdebugstring

I want to write a `UMDF2` windows driver, I don't know where to see the output from `OutputDebugString`.

This is my code, similar to [`KMDF Hello World`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver#write-your-first-driver-code).

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wdf.h>

NTSTATUS UmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd(_In_ WDFDRIVER Driver, _Inout_ PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    NTSTATUS status;
    WDFDEVICE hDevice;

    OutputDebugString((LPCWSTR)"UmdfHelloWorld: EvtDeviceAdd\n");

    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &hDevice);

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;

    OutputDebugString((LPCWSTR)"UmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry\n");

    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config, UmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd);
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject, RegistryPath, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &config, WDF_NO_HANDLE);
    
    return status;
}
```

Running the KMDF Hello World driver is giving me output successfully on `windbg` kernel-mode debugging.
However, the UMDF Hello World driver shows no output.

This is how I'm (un)installing drivers:

```
devcon.exe install UmdfHelloWorld.inf Root\UmdfHelloWorld
devcon.exe remove Root\UmdfHelloWorld
```

Also, I want to use user-mode debugging, but I don't know how to do that for UMDF drivers.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview

Answer (score 0):

> Umdf2 Hello World Driver, Where to see output?

Just as **Lex** said, you could use [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to view the output for UMDF drivers.

Besdies, you can try to [use WPP Software Tracing in UMDF Drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/using-wpp-software-tracing-in-umdf-drivers).

Comment: Or you can use WPP Software to trace in UMDF Drivers. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/using-wpp-software-tracing-in-umdf-drivers). Hope it could help you.

Comment: @AkshdeepSingh did you try to click on the ```Capture``` menu in Debug View and try enabling the various options?

Comment: You can just attach Visual Studio to the WDFhost.exe process, then you can see all debug-messages and you also can debug through your UMDF2 driver. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655392/debug-umdf-driver-without-two-machines for more details.